# React input inside modal component is losing focus and re-rendering state

Tags: reactjs, input

I have a modal component where I pass inputs for the props.children. When I type characters into either input, the input loses focuses after one character entry.

I have a few console.logs and I noticed each time I press a key, the console.log gets logged everytime. So i'm assuming the input loses focus because each time I enter a key, the state refreshes.

I've searched around for answers, and I found a few but they dont quite seem to work. The only one that does work but not in a very efficient way is using onBlur instead of onChange. The reason I dont want to use onBlur is because you have to click twice out of the input to click a button or start another input.

I have also tried adding a key to my input elements but that did not work either.

I'm also calling my Modal input in a render function that I then put in my JSX. I tried removing the modal from the function and put it straight into the JSX but that didnt work either.

So Im hoping someone may be able to help me out here!

This is the Modal function

```
const createTerminalsModal = (e) => {
return (
  <Modal
    modalHeader={<h2>Create New Terminal</h2>}
    hideButtons={false}
    buttonContent={"Save"}
    closeModal={setShow}
  >
     <>
      <label htmlFor="displayName">Terminal Display Name</label>
      <Input
        style={{ marginTop: "10px", marginBottom: "25px" }}
  
        name="displayName"
        defaultValue={values.displayName}
        onChange={handleInput}
      />
      <label htmlFor="pairingCode">Pairing Code</label>
      <Input
        style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}
        defaultValue={values.pairingCode}
        type="text"
        name="pairingCode"
        onChange={handleInput}
      />
    </>
  </Modal>
);
```

};

My input state and handleInput function

```
  const [values, setValues] = useState({ displayName: "", pairingCode: "" });

 const handleInput = () => {
const { name, value } = e.target;
setValues({
  ...values,
  [name]: value,
});
```

};

and then JSX here where I call the modal function

```
 return !terminals?.findManyStripeTerminalLocation.length ? (
    <>
      <div style={centered}>
        <h3>{clinicName} does not have configured terminals</h3>
        <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          <button onClick={createTerminalLocation} style={button}>
            Configure Terminals
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  ) : (
    <div>
      {show && createTerminalsModal()} <<<<<<<<<< Modal here
      <h1>Terminals for {clinicName}</h1>
      <div
        style={{
          textAlign: "right",
          paddingTop: "10px",
          paddingBottom: "10px",
        }}
      >
        <button onClick={showModal} style={button}>
          New +
        </button>
      </div>
      <table style={tableStyle}>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th style={tableHeaderStyle}>Terminal Name</th>
            <th style={tableHeaderStyle}>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {terminals?.findManyStripeTerminalLocation[0]?.terminals.map(
            (terminal) => {
              let healthCheck = terminal.healthchecks;
              let latestHealthCheck = healthCheck.slice(-1);
              return (
                <tr key={terminal.id}>
                  <td style={tableDataStyle}>{terminal.name}</td>
                  <td
                    style={
                      latestHealthCheck[0]?.status === "Online"
                        ? terminalOnline
                        : terminalOffline
                    }
                  >
                    {latestHealthCheck[0]?.status}
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            }
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And my Modal component

```
    export const NonGlobalModal = (props) => {

  return  (
    <Modal>
      <ModalContent size={props.size}>
        <ModalHeader>
          <Row>
            <C1>{props.modalHeader}</C1>
            <CA>
              <FaWindowClose
                size={32}
                style={{ margin: 8, cursor: "pointer" }}
                onClick={() => props.closeModal(false)}
              />
            </CA>
          </Row>
        </ModalHeader>
        <ModalInnerContent>{props.children}</ModalInnerContent>
        {!props.hideButtons ? (
          <ModalFooter>
            <Row>
              <C1 />
              <CA>
                <ModalButton style={{cursor: "pointer"}} onClick={props.click}>{props.buttonContent || "OK" }</ModalButton>
              </CA>
            </Row>
          </ModalFooter>
        ) : null}
      </ModalContent>
    </Modal>
  ) 
};
```

Comment: Posted my solution below, but if someone has a different idea Id love to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

I switched from useState to useRef to prevent re-rendering but still be able to capture the input value

```
  const displayNameRef = useRef(null)
  const pairingCodeRef = useRef(null)

const createTerminalsModal = () => {
    return (
      <Modal
        modalHeader={<h2>Create New Terminal</h2>}
        hideButtons={false}
        buttonContent={"Save"}
        closeModal={setShow}
        click={click}
      >
        <>
          <label htmlFor="displayName">Terminal Display Name</label>
          <Input
            style={{ marginTop: "10px", marginBottom: "25px" }}
            type="text"
            ref={displayNameRef}
          />
          <label htmlFor="pairingCode">Pairing Code</label>
          <Input
            style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}
            type="text"
            ref={pairingCodeRef}
          />
        </>
      </Modal>
    );
  };
```